# Post method not working on non-CRUD methods

Tags: 7, services

I'm just trying to create custom rest service action but I can't get it. I have created end_point called "testing". Whenever I try to post the data it shows access denied for authenticated user. Where I'm going wrong?

The steps I followed:

- used advanced rest client chrome extension
- http://localhost/testing/test/username
- In dataform I added data "username" = "abc";

I can't get the name. What I expecting is the post call must return the username "abc" according to my below function.

```
function my_module_service_services_resources() {        
    return array(
      'test' => array(
         'actions' => array(
            'username' => array(
              'check' => array(
                'help' => 'Checks username for uniqueness',
               'callback' => 'test_module_username_check',
               'access callback' => 'my_module_service_access',
                'access arguments' => array('view'),
                'access arguments append' => TRUE,
                'args' => array(
                  array(
                    'name' => 'username',
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'description' => 'The username to check',
                    'source' => 'data',
                    'optional' => FALSE,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
       ),
    );
  }


  function test_module_username_check($username) {
    return $username;
  }


  function my_module_service_access() {
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Make sure `Session authentication` checkbox is checked on your service endpoint, and flush all the caches. That should fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes @tyler. I have checked the session authenticated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging the action method of **user/login** (default in services module), I found where I went wrong. In my code, I added extra array called **check** inside **username**. When I remove that array everything is going well. Here the updated code

```
function my_module_service_services_resources() {        
    return array(
      'test' => array(
         'actions' => array(
            'username' => array(
              'help' => 'Checks username for uniqueness',
              'callback' => 'test_module_username_check',
              'access callback' => 'my_module_service_access',
              'access arguments' => array('view'),
              'access arguments append' => TRUE,
              'args' => array(
                array(
                  'name' => 'username',
                  'type' => 'string',
                  'description' => 'The username to check',
                  'source' => 'data',
                  'optional' => FALSE,
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
       ),
    );
  }


  function test_module_username_check($username) {
    return $username;
  }


  function my_module_service_access() {
    return true;
  }
```